# GridWalk CodeEval implementation issue

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm, optimization

This is a problem I am doing on CodeEval. It's a problem I've been working on for 4 hours.
I have seen another CodeEval GridWalk Problem post on here from 2 years ago, but it's hasn't helped me at all. If any has had experience with this problem, please read my code because I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

There is a monkey which can walk around on a planar grid. The monkey can move one space at a time left, right, up or down. That is, from (x, y) the monkey can go to (x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), and (x, y-1). Points where the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the x coordinate plus the sum of the digits of the absolute value of the y coordinate are lesser than or equal to 19 are accessible to the monkey. For example, the point (59, 79) is inaccessible because 5 + 9 + 7 + 9 = 30, which is greater than 19. Another example: the point (-5, -7) is accessible because abs(-5) + abs(-7) = 5 + 7 = 12, which is less than 19. How many points can the monkey access if it starts at (0, 0), including (0, 0) itself?
Input sample:

There is no input for this program.
Output sample:

Print the number of points the monkey can access. It should be printed as an integer — for example, if the number of points is 10, print "10", not "10.0" or "10.00", etc.

Submit your solution in a file (some file name).(py2| c| cpp| java| rb| pl| php| tcl| clj| js| scala| cs| m| py3| hs| go| bash| lua) or use the online editor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int z = 0, counter = 0, x = 0, y = 0, d = -1;

int verified(int x, int y);

int fill();

int main(void){
printf("%d",fill());
return 0;
}

//(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), and (x, y-1)

int fill(){
int i = 0;
while(d<1000000){  //I don't know how to make it so the program doesn't need a 
d++; i++;          //dimension for scanning. I have to end the loop somehow.

if(verified(x,y)){ //scan each point
                   //if x and y are accessible or "verified", increase point counter
counter++;
}else{;}  // do nothing

if((y%2)!= 0){  //increment each point
y += i;
continue;
}else if ((x%2)!=0){
x += i; 
continue;
}else if ((y%2) == 0){
y -= i;
continue;
}else if((x%2) == 0){
x -= i;
continue;
}



}
return counter; //return how many accessible points there are
}

int verified(int x , int y){
int r, digit = 0;
x = abs(x); y = abs(y);                //make x and y absolute
z = x * pow(10, (int)log10(y)+1) + y;
   //^append both values together(eg. x and y become xy)

while (z > 0) {   
 r = z % 10;        
 digit += abs(r);   // add all the digits of the sum together
 z /= 10;
}

if(digit <=19)   //if the sum is less than  or equal to 19, it's true
return 1;
else
return 0;
}
```

My output for this program was 575199. That apparently is not the write answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to do something like this
`z = x * pow(10, (int)log10(y)+1) + y;` because the cast (int) for `log10` function will always round down, so there will be two cases , when y is a pow of 10, and when y is not,  which is clearly not right for this part. You can fix it by calculate the sum for the digit one by one, for x first and then for y, you don't need to combine them.

Second, If I am not wrong, you can only move from an accessible point to another accessible point, so once again, this part is wrong:

```
if((y%2)!= 0){  //increment each point
    y += i;
    continue;
}else if ((x%2)!=0){
    x += i; 
    continue;
}else if ((y%2) == 0){
    y -= i;
    continue;
}else if((x%2) == 0){
    x -= i;
    continue;
}
```

Just blindly increase x and y will not guarantee that the point (x,y) is reachable, should handle this part by using BFS or DFS

Comment: Yes, the monkey can only move from one accessible point to another but all this segment of code does is move the point in order to prepare it to be evaluated by the "verified" function. (e.g., (x=0,y=0), (x=0, y=1), (x=1,y=1), (x=2,y=1), (x=2,y=-1)..The point traversing pattern implemented in the segment of code explicitly goes like this: (x+1 ,y+1) -> (x-2, y-2) -> (x-3, y-3)->(x+4, y+4)-> ..

Comment: @Rudy How do you make sure that the point (x + i, y + i) , (x + i, y - i) ... is reachable from one accessible point? you just check every point can be created by the loop, this is not right!, you should only check those reachable points.

Comment: @Rudy for example, point (280, 180) is valid right? but it cannot be reachable, because point (279,180) , point (280, 179) , point (281, 180) and point (280, 181) is not valid, so there is no way you can reach this point(280, 180) :D

Comment: @Rudy further more, in your loop, you didn't check cases when abs(x) and abs(y) is not equals, in your comment, you can clearly see that there is no way you can check point (2,1) or point(5,1)

Comment: did you have an idea of how to do this before you started writing the code for the solution? meaning, i'm completely clueless with respect do what a BFS or DFS algorithm is.

Comment: @Rudy it is normally if this is the first time you do something like this, one advice I can give you is do a lot of practicing, and If you stuck, read the solution and try to implement the solution. The is no short cut, only practicing :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following gives the correct answer (perhaps you could test it), but it shows the idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 600
#define LIMIT 19

char grid[SIZE][SIZE];

int sumdigs(int x) {
  int sum = 0;
  x = x < 0 ? -x : x;
  while (x != 0) { sum += x % 10; x /= 10; }
  return sum;
}

void walk(int x, int y) {
  int xx = x + SIZE / 2;
  int yy = y + SIZE / 2;
  if (xx < 0 || xx >= SIZE || yy < 0 || yy >= SIZE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "You need to make the grid larger.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if (sumdigs(x) + sumdigs(y) > LIMIT)
    return;
  if (grid[xx][yy] == 0) {
    grid[xx][yy] = 1;
    walk(x,   y+1);
    walk(x,   y-1);
    walk(x+1, y);
    walk(x-1, y);
  }
}

int count_accessible_points() {
  int cnt = 0;
  for(int y=0; y<SIZE; ++y)
    for(int x=0; x<SIZE; ++x)
      if (grid[x][y]) ++cnt;
  return cnt;
}

int main() {
  walk(0, 0);
  printf("%d\n", count_accessible_points());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: could you add comments explaining each process? why is the grid you made of type "char"? i'm trying to understand to the recursive function you implemented. at what point does it end?